# python - textarea text not getting using selenium

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The text was displayed in the textarea, but it was not included in element.
And I can find it in XHR response in browser network, how can I get it from the XHR response ?

This is how the website HTML calls the area where I'm trying to extract text:

```
<textarea class="text sr "
    wrap="off" id="arid_WIN_2_1000000161"
    cols="20" maxlen="15"
    style="top: 0px; left: 117px; width: 175px; height: 21px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"
    arautocak="0" arautoctt="400"
    arencryptdataatrest="0" rows="1" readonly="">
</textarea>
```

this is the response result:

```
this.result = {
  s: "null",
  oa: "fq0_1.SV(1000000621, {t: 7, v:\"1593581897\"}); fq0_1.SV(1000000161, {t: 4, v: \"INC0000AAAAAAAA\"});"
};

this.cacheIDRefCount = {
    "smt-backend": 1
};;
if (getCurWFC_NS(this.windowID) != null)
  getCurWFC_NS(this.windowID).status([]);
```

'INC0000AAAAAAAA' is text which I want.

Comment: I can only find the text in this response result from a XHR requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't fix the format of the response on the server, and you can trust on the data source, you can extract the data by using `eval` to parse the result string.

```js
const response = "fq0_1.SV(1000000621, {t: 7, v:\"1593581897\"}); fq0_1.SV(1000000161, {t: 4, v: \"INC0000AAAAAAAA\"});";
const calls = response.split(';');

const fq0_1 = {
  SV: function(arg, obj) {
    return eval(obj);
  }
};

const result = calls.map(str => {
  return eval(str);
});

console.log(result[1].v);
```

The code first splits the response text to array, each member containing a "method call". `fq0_1` is an object containing `SV` method, which is called in the evaluated code. Finally we create `result` array containing the objects in the method call arguments as live objects.

I suppose the response text is purposed to be parsed with a library (which has `fq0_1` object containing `SV` method, which does some actions based on the data).

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer that it can be scrap by .get_attribute('value') in selenium

Comment: @johnny92 Well, here you've asked "_how can I get it from the XHR response_", this is an answer to that question.